# PHP - How to match today and yesterday date with database field

Tags: php, mysql

i have got data in following format in database

```
  2015-01-16 14:53:02
```

i am trying to get record matach with today and another for yesterday date.

here is what i have tried

```
 //fetch today records
    if ($button1pressed=="T1"){
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
    $sqlquery="WHERE `datetime`="."'".$today."'";
    }

 //fetch yesterday records
    if ($button1pressed=="T2"){
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time() - 3600); 
    $sqlquery="WHERE `datetime`="."'".$yesterday."'";
    }
```

and sql is something like this.

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM  `me_olb1` ".$sqlquery ;
```

please need your help

thanks

Comment: `time() - 3600` is 1 hour ago, not yesterday.

Comment: Why don't you use `WHERE datetime = now()` and `WHERE datetime = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`?

Comment: but check the format of data and time in database which is 2015-01-16 14:53:02    as mention above

Comment: Why is it a `CHAR` column instead of `DATETIME`?

Comment: @Barmar is a? got from internet its doesn;t work anyways

Comment: i have complete my project working on reports now.... so no way to change filed for this purpose...

Comment: Look in to using parameterized queries, too. Just a guess, but that looks like a query destined for mysql_query -- not good.

Comment: Do you want to match the exact time of day in the database, or just the date part?

Comment: answer does the trick... :)

Comment: thanks everyone for involvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to work, it will only give you results for the exact same hour, minute and second.

You would need to extract the date from the datetime field. For example:

for today:

```
$sqlquery = " WHERE DATE(`datetime`)=DATE(NOW()) ";
```

for yesterday:

```
$sqlquery = " WHERE DATE(`datetime`)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ";
```